# Magento pass current product ID to module

Tags: caching, magento

I have a custom module that displays data on my product pages.  My module needs to get the current product id.  I tried using:

```
Mage::registry('current_product');
```

This works on the first load but when I refresh, current_product no longer has data with full page caching on.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The catalog product action controller isn't dispatched, when the full page cache handles the request (which makes sense to keep things fast).
So, the registry variables are never set.
I assume you are generating the block dynamically on the otherwise fully cached page.
My recommendation is to try to avoid expensive loads, since that would undermine the speed improvements by the full page cache. You really want to cache the block if at all possible, even if it's a separate cache entry for each customer and each product.

That said, here is how to do that:

In the container, implement the `_getIdentifier()` method:

```
protected function _getIdentifier()
{
    return $this->_getCookieValue(Enterprise_PageCache_Model_Cookie::COOKIE_CUSTOMER, '');
}
```

Also expand the `_getCacheId()` method to include the return value of the method _getIdentifier() and a new placeholder attribute: product_id

```
protected function _getCacheId()
{
    return 'HOMEPAGE_PRODUCTS' . md5($this->_placeholder->getAttribute('cache_id') . ',' . $this->_placeholder->getAttribute('product_id')) . '_' . $this->_getIdentifier();
}
```

Next, in the block class, extend the method `getCacheKeyInfo()`. All entries in the cache_key_info array with a string index are set on the placeholder as attributes. That is how we can pass the product id to the placeholder.

```
public function getCacheKeyInfo()
{
    $info = parent::getCacheKeyInfo();
    if (Mage::registry('current_product'))
    {
        $info['product_id'] = Mage::registry('current_product')->getId();
    }
    return $info;
}
```

Then enable the method `_saveCache()` by **not** overriding it in your container class and returning `false`.
So now, because the container returns a valid id from `_getCacheId()`, and `_saveCache()` is inherited from the parent class, the the block can be cached, and applied to the content in an efficient manner in `Enterprise_PageCache_Model_Container_Abstract::applyWithoutApp()`.

You can set the lifetime of the cache entry by having your container extend from `Enterprise_PageCache_Model_Container_Customer` instead of `Enterprise_PageCache_Model_Container_Abstract`.

If you still need to pass the product_id to the block (even though it's cached now), you can do so in the `_renderBlock()` method of your container:

```
protected function _renderBlock()
{
    $blockClass = $this->_placeholder->getAttribute('block');
    $template = $this->_placeholder->getAttribute('template');

    $block = new $blockClass;
    $block->setTemplate($template)
        ->setProductId($this->_placeholder->getAttribute('product_id'));
    return $block->toHtml();
}
```

Comment: Vinai - I setup the observer and still get "Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in"

Comment: Somehow I'm still not quite sure what exactly you want to accomplish, i.e. what you will do with the product ID and why the block needs to be generated dynamically. Maybe more information will help me give a better answer.

Comment: well this is for having a compare block on the product page.  right now it is getting cached and if you add a product to compare, the add to compare link is still there.  what I want to happen is for the add to compare link to be replaced with a delete compare and compare links:  `{domain}/catalog/product_compare/add/product/123456/` - add link  
`(domain}/catalog/product_compare/remove/product/123456/` - remove link  
`{domain}/catalog/product_compare/index/` - compare link

Comment: I updated my original answer based on this comment. Hope it helps now.

Comment: I have a related question (don't want to create a separate question so sorry for getting in the thread). What if I need to refresh the block immediately, I have product questions with ability to vote for helpfulness so I need to show updated stats on page reload. For now I return `false` in `_saveCache` but maybe there is a better solution? Implemented product id saving you proposed, before that I was using dirty hack reading value of `Enterprise_PageCache_Model_Container_Viewedproducts::COOKIE_NAME` cookie

Comment: If you want to receive the variable ProductId in your block on the FIRST load write: `if (Mage::registry('current_product'))
     {
     
         $product_id = Mage::registry('current_product')->getId();
     
     }
     else
     {
     
      $product_id = $this->getProductId();
     
     }` because `$product_id = $this->getProductId();` is unavaible on the first load because it needs to be saved the first time.

Comment: @Zifius I think I would look at pre-generating the cache entry directly instead of just invalidating the block cache record.

Answer (score 0):

you should have in the controller of your module something which init the registration of the current product. You will need to post between the page visited by a user the id of your product (recommended) or save it in a session. Here is an example of what you can do in a controller:

```
protected function _initAction(){

    if(! Mage::registry('current_product')){
        Mage::register('current_product', Mage::getModel('catalog/product'));
    }

    $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    if (!is_null($id)) {
        $model = Mage::registry('current_product')->load($id);

        if (! $model->getId()) {
            $this->_getSession()->addError(Mage::helper('catalog')->__('This product item no longer exists'));
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            return;
        }
    }

    return $this;
}

public function indexAction()
{
  $this->_initAction();
  // your code below
}
```

Comment: Diglin - I will try this but it is very similar to some things I have already tried - the issue is that when Mage::registry('current_product') is empty, so is everything else - therefore I don't believe Mage::register('current_product', Mage::getModel('catalog/product')); will do anything