# Magento Mage::registry('current_product'); not working if magento cache is enable

Tags: php, magento, caching

As I am using Mage::registry to get an current product ID in footer.phtml as below

but If my magento cache is enable then I am not able to get correct ID's

`$current_product_id = Mage::registry('current_product')->getId();`

Is anything I am missing here?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8174021/magento-pass-current-product-id-to-module

Answer (score 3):

You will need to set the footer block to be uncached.

`footer.phtml` only reads the registry the first time the block is created. After that, the footer contents are read from the cache.

All dynamic content in Magento must be created each time it is used, not read from cache.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3124/how-can-i-disable-cache-for-particular-section-or-block

Comment: Thanks @Fiasco moved code to header.phtml now Mage::registry works fine

Comment: How wrong is this statement: **All dynamic content in Magento must be created each time it is used, not read from cache.**

Answer (score 1):

Let try after to clear the cache, simply delete everything from the **[APP ROOT]/var/cache** directory and then reload your website in your browser.

Comment: I tried this but first time it works but when I visit to any another product page then it gives me prev product id